# Correct usage of replacing cuss words with symbols

Tags: offensive-language

I've noticed that symbols (i.e. #, $, %, !, *, etc.) are commonly used to filter profanity/foul language.

Just out of curiosity, is there a specific way to do this.  I've noticed sometimes there isn't a specific number of symbols but normally the number of symbols correspond to the number of letters in the cuss word. E.g.:

> Wow dude, you are such an &#%-hole!

---

So, with that all in mind:

1. What symbols are acceptable for doing this?
2. Are there patterns or specific methods for this?  (Specific patterns for certain words)
3. Other rules that may pertain to the situation.

Comment: “Cuss word” is an interesting construct itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Standard practice is to substitute asterisk when replacing just some letters (especially vowels, and not normally the first or last letter) in a swear-word (for example - "sh*t", or "c**t").

Any random combination of other "special" characters (including but not limited to &#%!@?) may be used to denote "some unspecified swear-word".

I think OP's specific example is at least "unusual" usage. I would normally expect either "You're such an &#%!@?!", or "You're such an a***hole".

Also note that particularly with longer words such as "bollocks" (which the markup language won't let me "clean up" here), the number of asterisks may not accurately reflect the number of letters substituted. So you don't need to wonder whether my a***hole was British or American!

Comment: Lol. I assume its the same nationality as the rest of you. ;-)

Comment: Sometimes symbols that are similar to the replaced letters are used, such as "@$$hole", but it may happen that there isn't a symbol that resembles the letter being replaced.

Comment: The random **!&?@#!#%&!** thing is especially used in Comics, such as [Donald Duck](http://www.fanboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/SymbolSwearing.jpg)'s. :)

Comment: @Frustrated: The use of similar-looking characters is from "leet", a style of writing popularized by the Internet.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: I think that "leet" style is mainly used by younger people on software-monitored "safe sites" to avoid alerting a human moderator. In other contexts, since the letters are clearly-recognisable to human eyes, why bother?

Comment: @KeithS: I wasn't sure if it originated with 13375p34k as I was pretty sure I'd seen it in years ago in material (comic book, I think?) that predated the Web. But it was a long time ago, so no, I don't have references :(

Comment: Well, the use of random symbols to replace swear words predates the Internet by a fair number of decades. But, they're random, and not one-to-one substitutes.

Answer (score 8):

These symbol sets are defined as a "grawlixes". For additional information, please refer to Wikipedia: [The Lexicon of Comicana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lexicon_of_Comicana).